# 2 checkboxes for ball's area and circumference

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have an html file with form with 2 checboxes in it, and I wanted to calculate the area and circumference of ball, but the form doesn't return any value...

HTML file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ball</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">

Enter radius: <br><br>
<input type="text" name="radius"> <br><br>

    Area:
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1"><br>
    Circumference:
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2"><br>

<button type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP file (I used foreach loop):

```
<?php
$radius = $_POST['radius'];

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {

            if ($check == "0")
            {
                $result1 = 4*3.14*($radius*$radius);
                echo "Area: " . $result1."<br>";

            }
            if ($check == "1")
            {
                $result2 = 4/3*3.14*($radius*$radius*$radius);
                echo "Circumference: " . $result2 . "<br>";             
            }
}
?>
```

Why it doesn't work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your current values of area and circumference check boxes are "value 1" and "value 2". Those are the values you get in the php code.

So in the if condition check for those values. i.e if($check=="value 1") or if($check ==" value 2").

But a better practice is to change the value check boxes to just "0" and "1".
It will be more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Change the values of the checkbox items to value="0" for the area and value="1" for the Circumference

Then change the condition on your loop:

foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $option => $check)

Comment: also change :
if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
to:
if(isset($_POST['check_list']))